# Visual Basic Parsing Child Nodes

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to access a child node using visual basic

JSON:

```
{
  "ts": 1613329726937,
  "tsj": 1613329725821,
  "date": "Feb 14th 2021, 02:08:45 pm NY",
  "items": [
    {
      "curr": "GBP",
      "xauPrice": 1318.1226,
      "xagPrice": 19.7657,
      "chgXau": 2.2943,
      "chgXag": 0.1114,
      "pcXau": 0.1744,
      "pcXag": 0.5668,
      "xauClose": 1315.82831,
      "xagClose": 19.65425
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I am trying is:

```
Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
Me.lblGold.Text = "£" + json.SelectToken("items")("xauPrice").ToString()
```

However I don't believe this is the correct syntax?

Comment: `items` is an array, you need to specify the index.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me

```
 Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
 Me.lblGold.Text = "£" + json.SelectToken("items")(0)("xauPrice").ToString()
```